# How to sum values by a common attribute before a sort in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to sort records in my table in Rails 4 by values in the `Points` column of my model.

That part is easy, but I have an additional complexity: I want to use .`sum` for all values with matching `user_id` before this sort. In other words, I want to `.order` the total points belonging to a user, which may include multiple values.

First, to produce a general order, I tried:

```
@orders = Point.order(points: :desc)
@total = @orders.sum(:points)
```

This produces a general sum of values in this table. However, I instead want to use `.sum` to add values with matching `user_id` before performing @orders.

To be more clear, here is what the **Points.rb** table looks like.

**Points.rb Table Example**

```
|user_id: 1| points: 10 | game_id 3|
|user_id: 1| points: 20 | game_id 2|
|user_id: 2| points: 50 | game_id 3|
|user_id: 3| points: -10 | game_id 1|
```

Is this possible with mysql to group, sum, and then sort without needing to create new, aggregate values in the original table?

Comment: Try User.points.sum(:points) , Write your mapping bw user & point for more clarification

Comment: I removed my code above and tried to run yours. I am receiving a `undefined method `points' ` error for User.points.sum(:points). I should also note that User has a has_many relationship to Points, which made me think this would work. No luck yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try next query:

```
Point.order(points: :desc).group(:user_id).sum(:points)
#=> {2 => 50, 1 => 30, 3 => -10}
```

This code produces SQL next query:

> SELECT SUM(`points`.`points`) AS sum_points, user_id AS user_id FROM
>   `points` GROUP BY `points`.`user_id`  ORDER BY `points`.`points` DESC

Comment: Testing now. The logic of your suggestion makes sense to me, but I continue seeing a `undefined method `points' for [nil, 300]:Array`. This doesn't make sense to me, as the group should ideally populate the first value with an integer representing user_id. Trying to debug now.

Comment: I should also add for reference that I am trying to iterate through all user_ids with their grouped points in my view like so:         `<% @points.each do |point| %>
                                 <td><%= point.points %></td>
                                 <td><%= point.user_id %></td>
                         <% end %>`

Comment: I think, you need to set 0 as default value for points in your database.

Comment: Currently doing so. From my Points migration: `t.integer :points, default: 0`. I think the "300" is the points value -- it seems to be missing the grouped ID.

Comment: @darkginger, I think same

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming that user has many points & your points table contains a column named "point", so your controller code should be similar to below:

```
@user = User.all
@user.each do |u|
   puts u.points.sum(:point)
end
```

Comment: I just try this in my system & it works , I don't understand that who has voted down this answer

Comment: i think, problem is that author want to do it with SQL query.

Comment: @llya: as per the question, it seems that author want rails code & not sql query

Comment: you just print result in console, but you should aggregate it. By the way, your code produces N+1 queries to database instead of 1.